# DAG-level Params for string and integer

Tags: python, airflow

I have a Airflow `SparkSubmitOperator` and I want to add DAG-level Params to configure:

```
executor_cores
executor_memory
application_args
```

I’ve wrote next code:

```
dag = DAG(
    'spark_submit_ex',
    params={
        "executor_cores": Param(2, type="integer", minimum=2),
        "executor_memory": Param("4g", type="string"),
        "some_id": Param("file_sink", type="string")
    },
….  
)

spark_job = SparkSubmitOperator(
    executor_cores='{{ params.executor_cores }}',
    driver_memory='{{ params.driver_memory }}',
    application='0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar',
    application_args=['{{ params.some_id }}'],
    …..
```

In airflow logs I see the correct value for `application_args` and incorrect for `executor_cores` and `driver_memory`:

```
- Spark-Submit cmd: spark-submit 
….. 
 --executor-cores {{ params.executor_cores }} --executor-memory {{ params.executor_memory }} 
….
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar --workspaceId file_sink
```

I also tried to use double quotes ( `executor_cores='{{ params.executor_cores }}'`) and DAG did not start in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

executor_cores and driver_memory are not in the template_fields of this SparkSubmitOperator - see this [source code](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/airflow/providers/apache/spark/operators/spark_submit.py)

You can create your own Operator that inherits from SparkSubmitOperator and add both to the exsiting template_fields

```
class SparkSubmitOperatorEx(SparkSubmitOperator):
    template_fields: Sequence[str] = (
        "_application",
        "_conf",
        "_files",
        "_py_files",
        "_jars",
        "_driver_class_path",
        "_packages",
        "_exclude_packages",
        "_keytab",
        "_principal",
        "_proxy_user",
        "_name",
        "_application_args",
        "_env_vars",
        "_driver_memory",
        "_executor_cores",
    )
```